# Migrate simple Custom Renderer from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, custom-renderer

I'm trying to migrate a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI. So far I've managed to port almost everything, but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to rewrite a custom renderer for a ScrollView using the new MAUI paradigm (handlers). The Xamarin renderer is very simple. I just need to override OnIntereptTouchEvent and OnTouchEvent:

```
    class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public MyScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            /* nothing here */
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (((MyScrollView)Element).ScrollingEnabled)
            {
                return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (((MyScrollView)Element).ScrollingEnabled)
            {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The meaning of this renderer is to disable the ScrollView scrolling while the user interacts with a custom component to trace some lines on the screen. On iOS this is pretty simple. It's just a matter of setting `handler.PlatformView.ScrollEnabled = false;`. On Android this property do not exist, so, the need to override `OnInterceptTouchEvent` and `OnTouchEvent`.

I've read through the MAUI docs, but just found ways to map property changes with handlers. Couldn't find any guidance on how to implement and register a method override using the same approach (I really don't want to use the compatibility namespace, if possible). Any clue on this regard will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom handler doesn't support to override the platform view's method. If you want to override it, you need to create a custom platform view. Here is my code:

```
namespace MauiApp10.Platforms.Android
{
    // declare the custom platform view
    public class MyScrollView : MauiScrollView
    {
        public bool scroallable = true;
        public MyScrollView(Context context) : base(context){}
        public MyScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { }
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
           switch (e.Action)
           {
             case MotionEventActions.Down: return scroallable&& base.OnTouchEvent(e);
             default: return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
           }
        }
        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
          return scroallable && base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    // declare the custom handler
    public class MyHandler : ScrollViewHandler
    {
        protected override MauiScrollView CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var scrollView = new MyScrollView(
new ContextThemeWrapper(MauiContext!.Context, Resource.Style.scrollViewTheme), null!,
Resource.Attribute.scrollViewStyle)
            {
                ClipToOutline = true,
                FillViewport = true
            };
            return scrollView;
        }
       
    }
}
```

And use the custom handler in the program.cs:

```
                  .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                  {
#if ANDROID
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(MyHandler));
#endif
                  });
```

And disable the scrollview in the button click event:

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
            var myscrollview = scrollview.Handler.PlatformView as MyScrollView;
          // the scrollview is the x:Name in the xaml
            myscrollview.scroallable = false;
#endif
      }
```

And I see you used custom control and custom renderer in the xamarin.forms, you can [create the property mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-property-mapper) to map the custom control's scrollable property to the andorid platform view.

Comment: This really did the trick! Thank you very much :)