# Why does a ScrollViewRenderer make my ScrollView contents disappear in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, custom-renderer

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. I have a Xamarin.Forms application which I am migrating to MAUI. I have a ScrollViewRenderer which I am adding to my project. For the sake of simplicity I have reduced the ScrollViewRenderer to be empty, as shown in the following code:

```
    public class StyledScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public StyledScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
    }
```

I enable this renderer with the following line:

```
builder
   .UseMauiApp<App>()
   ...
   .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
   {
#if ANDROID
       handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(StyledScrollViewRenderer));
#endif
   })
```

If I run my application with the StyledScrollViewRenderer added, the contents of all scroll views are empty. If I comment out the AddCompatibilityRenderer, all contents in all ScrollViews render correctly.

Am I misunderstanding something about scrollViewRenderers? I was under the impression that these could be used to modify the existing appearance and behavior of particular views, but perhaps ScrollViewRenderer requires additional code for default rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was unable to figure out how to solve this using the same renderer that I used in Xamarin.Forms, but it seems as if using a ScrollViewHandler (the new MAUI way of doing Renderers) seems to work well. I followed this answer to get past the issue I was having.

[Migrate simple Custom Renderer from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241273/migrate-simple-custom-renderer-from-xamarin-forms-to-net-maui?rq=2)

Comment: .NET MAUI only support [the renderer derives from FrameRenderer, ListViewRenderer, ShellRenderer on iOS and Android, TableViewRenderer, and VisualElementRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers#shimmed-renderers). For other controls, .NET MAUI provides [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/#handler-based-views) with higher performance to replace `renderer`.

Comment: While this answers the question, it's very problematic to developers with large Xamarin.Forms projects migrating to MAUI. In my case it took weeks to do.